# How to bulk delete email accounts from cPanel / my hosting account?

Tags: email, cpanel, hostgator

I'd like to delete a few hundred email accounts from my domain (it's not all of them).

I've looked and looked. cPanel and Hostgator allow you to bulk-create email accounts and forwarders and [there may be a way to bulk-delete forwarders](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/47707/42115) but there doesn't seem to be a way to ***delete*** email accounts -- except one click at a time.

So, if I have 197 email accounts to delete:

```
account_003@mydomain.com
account_004@mydomain.com
account_012@mydomain.com
account_027@mydomain.com
etc...
```

How can I do this in bulk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally stumbled on [the `delpop` command and cPanel's command-line interface](http://cpanel.net/system-administrators/command-line-scripts/).

So, assuming:

1. You have SSH access to your account
2. Your host has installed cPanel in the usual way

Then you can delete a single email account with this command, using an SSH client like PuTTY:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/cpanel-email delpop account_003 0 mydomain.com
```

---

To delete many accounts, all on domain `mydomain.com`, do this:

1. Create a text file, `delemails.txt`, with each account name on its own line:

   ```
   account_003
   account_004
   account_012
   account_027
   etc...
   ```
2. FTP that file onto your server into a convenient location.
3. SSH onto your server and `cd` to the location where you placed `delemails.txt`
4. Run this command from the SSH shell:

   ```
   for i in `cat delemails.txt`; do /usr/local/cpanel/cpanel-email delpop "$i" 0 mydomain.com ; done
   ```

   It takes a couple of minutes to loop through 197 accounts and you'll see status messages printing for each account.
5. Done!

Answer (score 2):

To improve the answer provided by **Brock Adams**.

At this time the `/usr/local/cpanel/cpanel-email` command doesn't work as it should, at least not for me.

So I had to use the UAPI function for this purpose and it works like a charm.

You can check the full documentation from here: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/DD/UAPI+Functions+-+Email%3A%3Adelete_pop

The final command should be something like:

```
for i in `cat email-accts.txt`; do /usr/local/cpanel/bin/uapi --user=CPANEL-USER Email delete_pop email="$i" domain=DOMAIN ; done
```

Hope this helps. :)